# Spring Boot - client server REST API with self-signed certificate

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-boot, ssl-certificate

I made two apps for client and server with `RestTemplate` `RestController`.

Needed to encrypt API with self-signed certificate, 'RestController' on server side should answer only to signed requests.

Is it possible with Spring Boot `RestTemplate` / `RestController`?

- how to do it
- on client side
- on server side

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can find on the net to use ssl in spring boot Rest. If you want to use a client like RestTemplate, you need to add the certificate to your JRE : lib/security/cacerts. You can find on the net how to do that too.

Answer (score 2):

The Spring Boot doc provides informations on how to configure the server:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-ssl

For configuring the client RestTemplate see here (4. The Spring RestTemplate with SSL)
http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl